# Get sender accountid when transfering assets from relaychain to parachain

Tags: parachain, xcm, relay-chain

I have a local rococo relay chain and my own parachain.
For `AssetTransactor` type of `xcm_executor` I use my own implementation of `TransactAsset` trait.

When I send tokens from relaychain to parachain from `Bob` account to `Alice` using reserveTransfer on relaychain. On parachain side the `deposit_asset` method of `TransactAsset` trait implementation is called and it works well. It looks like I need a Origin Multilocation of a tokens sender(`Bob`) in my custom implementation - but there is no such argument in this function, only the Multilocation of tokens reciever(`Alice`).

Is there any way to send tokens with the sender address not erased? For example, `TransactAsset` trait has a `transfer_asset` method that takes the sender Multilocation - can it be used to send tokens in this case - and what XCM message should be used if it possible?

Comment: Why do you need the sender's origin?

Comment: just need it in logic

Answer (score 2):

In XCM v3, there is the `DescendOrigin` instruction which allows you to specify a `Junction`, which will be appended at the end of the current origin. We call this the Computed Origin. The origin that sent the XCM is called the Physical Origin.

To use a Web 2.0 analogy, a Computed Origin is akin to an IP address, whereas a Physical Origin is akin to a MAC address.

To answer your question more specifically, you can use the `AccountId32` variant in the `Junction` enum and put it in a `DescendOrigin` instruction. That will mutate the `origin` register in the XCM executor, making sure that each subsequent XCM instruction processed afterwards would use the Computed Origin, which contains the account ID of the person who sent the XCM instruction.